# Expand parent list in child classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm not sure what would be the best way of modeling this in C#, I'm going to try to explain what I want to do. I'm connecting to a SOAP API (I have no control of) that returns several types of entities. There are some shared fields for all the entities and some others that are specific to certain types of entities. There are actually several levels as in any regular inheritance structure.

When I request an entity through the API, no matter the type, I have to send the list of fields I want and the entity type and I get back a generic Entity object with a list of values for those fields.

I would like to recreate the original classes in the other system in mine, keeping the inheritance structure. I would like my classes to have a list of the fields specific to them plus the list of fields specific to the parent they are inheriting from. Something like this:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Fields
    {
       get { return new List<string> {"field1"}; }
    }
}

public class ChildEntity:BaseEntity 
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Fields
    {
        get 
        { 
            var fields = new List<string> {"field2"}; 
            fields.AddRange(base.Fields);
            return fields;
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this would work more or less, taking into account the risk of a child class removing the parent fields (but that would be sorted out partially by not assuming you can't have null values in the properties and dealing with that). This is how the request part would look like:

```
ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest()
request.Id = "1";
request.Type = "ChildEntity";
request.Fields = ChildEntity.Fields // This is what I want to get dynamically somehow
RemoteEntity remoteEntity = apiClient.Request(request);
ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity(remoteEntity); // It parses the expected values
```

However, the list of fields should actually be static. I want to access it before making a request for the fields to the server, so I don't have any class instance, and thus I cannot use this inheritance solution. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use a custom attribute for this. I think it's a more elegant and maintainable solution as I don't have the risk of child classes overriding the parent fields.

```
[EntityFields("field1","field2")]
public class BaseEntity 
{
    public ISet<string> Fields
    {
        get
        {
            Type typeToCheck = GetType();
            ISet<string> fields = new HashSet<string>();

            do
            {
                var entityFieldsAttribute =
                    (EntityFields) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeToCheck, typeof (EntityFields));
                if (entityFieldsAttribute != null)
                {
                    fields.UnionWith(entityFieldsAttribute.Fields);
                }
                typeToCheck = typeToCheck.BaseType;
            } while (typeToCheck != typeof (BaseEntity));

            return fields;
        }
    }
}

[EntityFields("field3","field4")]
public class ChildEntity:BaseEntity 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to do it:

1: Define the field inheritance relationships explicitly, a la:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    protected static readonly string[] fields = { "field1" };
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields
    {
        get { return fields; }
    }
}

public class ChildEntity : BaseEntity
{
    protected static readonly string[] fields = { "field2" } ;
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields
    {
        get { return BaseEntity.Fields.Concat(fields); }
    }
}

public class GrandChildEntity : ChildEntity
{
    protected static readonly string[] fields = { "field3" } ;
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields
    {
        get { return ChildEntity.Fields.Concat(fields); }
    }
}

// Result:
// BaseEntity.Fields == { "field1" };
// ChildEntity.Fields == { "field1", "field2" };
// GrandChildEntity.Fields == { "field1", "field2", "field3" };
```

Not so pretty or super-efficient, but slightly better than having to explicitly define the entire list of `fields` in every class.

2: Use reflection to directly get the list of properties that exist in each class, and remove the ones that aren't actually fields in the API object model:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    private static readonly string[] fields = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Where(name => !name.Equals("Fields")).ToArray();
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields { get { return fields; } }
    public object field1 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private static readonly string[] fields = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Where(name => !name.Equals("Fields")).ToArray();
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields { get { return fields; } }
    public object field2 { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChildEntity : ChildEntity
{
    private static readonly string[] fields = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Where(name => !name.Equals("Fields")).ToArray();
    public static IEnumerable<string> Fields { get { return fields; } }
    public object field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that would not work with more levels of inheritance, as you are harcoding the parent type. Also that hides the parent method and could potentially cause issues, but probably not in this context when I'm getting the fields from the most specific class. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: To get the field data without an instance of the class, there is no other choice but to use a static member.  I added a 2nd example using reflection which avoids referencing the parent class(es) directly, but still uses static members.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to recreate the original classes in the other system in mine

Visual Studio can do exactly that via `Add Service Reference`.  It automatically generates proxy classes from the target web service.  This would save you from doing the work yourself.

Just right-click in your project and choose Add Service Reference.  The dialog is mostly self-explanatory.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) is a brief how-to (it mentions WCF but you can ignore that, it's the same for all web services).

Comment: Yes, I did that initially, but the web service is only exposing a generic class for all the entities as I tried to explain. That's why I want a way of inheriting and expanding the field names from parents to children, but I cannot find a really good way (maintenable and not prone to errors) of doing so.